# Is there a possibility to show axios version at runtime

Tags: javascript, npm, axios

I am currently using axios through npm `import axios from 'axios'`

Is there o possibility to console.log the axios version after the whole application has been built?

Comment: Stab in the dark, but can you import `axios/package.json` and read the version property?

Comment: Are you running nodejs or web context ?

Comment: @Matthew, Yes, but this is something that I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Peterrabbit I am using node

Answer (score 0):

You could execute a bash command from nodejs to get an output of `npm ls` for axios.

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('npm ls | grep axios', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(`Axios package: ${stdout}`);
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```